# Use sharedpreferences inside class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

I am having a problem using my shared preferences inside a class. My code and program flow:

I have a `Spinner` inside my activity.I am implementing my own OnItemSelectedListener like this:

**MyOnItemSelectedListener.java**

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener  {
     SharedPreferences pref;
     Editor editor;

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        //parent.setSelection(7);
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected Country : " + parent.getItemIdAtPosition(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

I call the above class from my activity like this:

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

So far so good.What i want is to save the selected item on `spinner1` to the user's preferences(and set it from saved value).

Inside an activity i am using my shared prefs like this:

`pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);`

but inside the class the context doesn't exists! Any help retrieving/saving pref when the user selects an item on the spinner?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you get the context or the preferences themselves in the activity and then pass them to MyOnItemSelectedListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a constructor for your listener and pass a `Context` to it:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener  {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    Editor editor;

    public MyOnItemSelectedListener(Context context) {
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: It works,thank you. I now call the call with spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(this.getApplicationContext())); I'll accept when i can.