# Calling SharedPreferences from a separate class with a spinner?

Tags: android, class, sharedpreferences, listener, android-spinner

I'm not sure how to word this but I'm having issues accessing Shared Preferences under MODE_PRIVATE.

I'm implementing a Spinner like so:

```
setSessions = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.numSessions);
setSessions.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
```

The Custom listener is like so:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

        SharedPreferences defaultPrefs;
        defaultPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Defaults", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedSessions = defaultPrefs.getString("tcpCapSessions", "None Set");

        if (savedSessions != parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()) {
        final Editor defaultEdit = defaultPrefs.edit();  
        defaultEdit.putString("tcpCapSessions", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());              // Writes the key "Default Server" along with Server Name chosen (as the value).
        defaultEdit.commit();
        }

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
                "Sessions set to: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I'm getting an error on the "**MODE_PRIVATE**" when getting SharedPreferences....

[image]

I simply want to update a preference depending on the users selection. I've tried extending the Activity which gets rid of the error but the app will still crash on first launch.

I've checked out [Use sharedpreferences inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768926/use-sharedpreferences-inside-class) but it hasn't helped me resolve the issue, may be it's missing something as it appears like the same issue as myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MODE_PRIVATE` is a static member of `Context`. It's actually described pretty good [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

change it to `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`

Comment: I do that and then I and error on the getSharedPreferences() stating: The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type CustomOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: Dude, follow the link and read! `getSharedPreferences()` also is in Context.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Genius try this..

1. Shared Preferences allow you to save and retrieve data in the form of key,value pair.
2. You have to call a method getSharedPreferences() that returns a SharedPreferences instance pointing to the file that contains the values of preferences.

   ```
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   ```

The first parameter is the **Name** and the second parameter is the **MODE**.

## Name:

Desired preferences file. If a preferences file by this name does not exist, it will be created when you retrieve an editor (SharedPreferences.edit()) and then commit changes (Editor.commit()).

## Mode:

(Operating Mode)

- **0** or **MODE_PRIVATE** for the default operation.
- **MODE_WORLD_READABLE** and **MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE** to control permissions.
- **MODE_MULTI_PROCESS** can also be used if multiple processes are mutating the same SharedPreferences file.

**Example:**

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

  //Initialize SharedPreferences.

    public static SharedPreferences.Editor editUserSelection;
public static SharedPreferences prefUserSelection;
public static final String GET_USER_PREF = "get_my_user";

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

     //save user selected position.
    prefUserSelection = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GET_USER_PREF, 0);
    editUserSelection= prefUserSelection.edit();
     editUserSelection.putInt("user", pos);
     editUserSelection.commit();
     }
```

For retrieve the user position,

```
prefUserSelection = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(GET_USER_PREF, 0);
int userSelected = prefUserSelection .getInt("user", 0); //0 is the default value
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User Selected Position: "+userSelected ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I get an error on the "getApplicationContext()." area. Just asks me to create a method for it.